# SSL Only Facebook Page Tab

Tags: facebook, ssl

I would like to configure both the **Page Tab URL** and the **Secure Page Tab URL** to use SSL connection.

I filled these two field with https://www.myapp.com/, however when opening the tab with a non-ssl fan page, the page tab url is http://www.myapp.com.

Is there a way to enforce Facebook to always use the HTTPS address?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a bug, and Facebook's official response is that it's "by design."

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/220661014669375

Comment: Facebug sometimes is unbelievable

Answer (score -1):

You can have http://www.myapp.com/ redirect to https://www.myapp.com/.

Comment: If I do this on my server, then I lose the signed_request params.